# Best practices around Silverlight 2 GDR 1?

Tags: silverlight

I noticed a few tweets this morning about a new version of Silverlight having been released - Silverlight 2 GDR 1 (2.0.40115.0).  Details of what/why/should I target it/is it backward compatible/etc seem incredibly thin on the ground.

Hitting this [Silverlight page on Microsoft.com](http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/resources/install.aspx) tells me my version (RTW) is now out of date and I should upgrade to GDR 1.  But hitting [silverlight.net](http://silverlight.net/) - there's no mention of it, the Silverlight elements on the page don't tell me my version is out of date and the Getting Started page still links to RTW tools.

This kinda leads me to presume that if you upgrade your dev tools to target the GDR release, then your users will need to upgrade their Silverlight install also?

A few details on what's in GDR can be found in the [release notes](http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/D/8/FD8F5947-78FF-40A5-9A34-5E35243C12E4/40115/Microsoft%20Silverlight%20Release%20History.html) - but it sure would be nice if Microsoft would clarify it's purpose and suggested adoption.  Anyone got any more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tim Heuer explains all: http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/02/19/silverlight-2-gets-minor-update-gdr1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be only bug fixing.

So if your applications (so your users) are not concerned by those bugs, it is not mandatory to update your plugin for the moment.

Comment: I think I agree - I'm just surprised Microsoft haven't made this clearer.  It seems that if you target GDR in your development, then your end users will be forced to upgrade.  I worry that a lot of developers will just upgrade as a matter of course without taking that into consideration.